# Underestimation of slope of linear regression line by Numpy's polyfit function?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I'm doing a linear regression using pretty basic numpy/matplotlib code that seems to be standard from what I've read in the docs and other questions on that topic here at stackoverflow:

```
ax.scatter(obs, sim, s=1, color='black', alpha=0.05)
z = np.polyfit(obs, sim, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
ax.plot(obs,p(obs),"r-")
```

The input arrays (obs and sim) are two relatively large 1D arrays (277606 values each) representing values of two raster files with equal pixel sizes and counts.

When plotting the results for several test datasets, it seems to me like the regression line is always too flat (see example images below).

Is this just an illusion or is it possible that the code actually miscalculates the regression parameters? What would be an appropriate test to check whether the linear fit is correct?

[Example plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T7Xu.png)
[Example plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT187.png)
[Example plot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOx5S.png)
[Example plot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z95wG.png)

Comment: Your eyes are not a robust estimator at all. You do not know the distribution of points in the black area, you only know that the black area has so many points to appear totally black. To remove your doubts, you may provide your code and dataset, as [Help Center suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Consider your first plot, "Example plot 1".  You have two obvious clusters in the lower-left and upper-right corners.  If you had *only* those clusters, and not the rest of the points scattered through the roughly rectangular region, you would expect the line to go through the centers of the clusters.  But in fact the lower-left cluster has a lot of points far above it, pulling the line up on that side, and the upper-right cluster has a lot of points far below it pulling the line down.  So the slope of the line it not too surprising.

Comment: @sentence I have uploaded the [example data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhqdu2qryso8d5r/obs_sim.tar.gz?dl=1). In agreement with the Help Center suggestions I kept the code focused on the part that actually matters for the question. If there are any questions regarding the code please feel free to ask.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Good point, I did not consider the bias in the scatter at the upper and lower ends of the value range. That basically answers my question.